# Node js, express. Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Использую express, отдаю html. Не грузятся картинки. По такой причине:

```
Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' *.picsum.photos".
```

В meta пытался добавить - не катит.

Поставил helmet-csp, отключил helmet.

```
app.use(csp({
directives: {
    defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
    imgSrc: ["'self'", '*.picsum.photos']
}
```

}))

Не работает!

Вот заголовок, что отдает express:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';img-src 'self' *.picsum.photos
```

Картинки грузятся отсюда: https://picsum.photos/200/300

Что не так?

Comment: `<URL>` — это что?

Comment: Так хром собирает группу типичных ошибок.
Это сообщение можно развернуть, и посмотреть - какие изображениея вызвали данные ошибки. Тогда будет этот сайт: https://picsum.photos (какртинки с него)
В итоге одна ошибка на одно фото с этого сайта.
Типа:
https://picsum.photos/200/300
https://picsum.photos/200/301

Comment: Эм, ну так надо убрать звёздочку. `*.picsum.photos` — это поддомены

Comment: Это из mdn: Администратор веб-сайта хочет разрешить контент из доверенного домена и всех его поддоменов (это не обязательно должен быть тот же домен, на котором установлен CSP).

Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' *.trusted.com